# Display Pivot Table based on Listdata using SP 2010 Standard Edition

Tags: pivot-tables

I need to create a pivot table on a webpart page with multiple x dimensions based on list data.

e.g.

```
----Status  Started Completed In Progress
----Prio    Hi  Lo  Hi    Lo  Hi      Lo
Task
A           1   2   1     4   5       0
B           3   0   0     0   1       0
C           2   1   1     1   1       6
```

I've found the http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/pivotpoint/ webpart, which is nearlly what I need, but only supports on x dimension (ie. no prio as in the example)

Does anybody now another webpart which can handle this? 
I currenlty don't have access to the enterprise license, but could maybe get access to it:
- The excel viewer webpart would not be solution, as it requires a manual refresh of the connected list data, to get the view updated
- would the performance point services have a suitable webpart?

I'm also open to any other suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say "...only supports **one** x dimension..."?  I have not used PivotPoint, but I wonder if you could treat this as if there is only one x series instead of two. In other words "Started Hi", "Started Lo", "Completed Hi", "Completed Lo", and so forth...

Another thing I've seen (poor man's approach) is to make use of a custom summary list to pull this off.  Basically, you would create a list with the columns you've identified in your post.  Set the list to automatically refresh via SharePoint 2010's new [Asynchronous Update settings](http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=64).  Then use event handlers on the source task list (when a task is created, started or completed), or queries in a timer job, to keep that list current.  This will require some Visual Studio development.

Finding something that updates automatically is going to be difficult. Even if you find a solution it would likely be taxing on your server -- especially if multiple people are hitting it at once.

By the way, what is the difference between "Started" and "In Progress" in your example? I'm curious about your application as I am a constant learner when it comes to BI and dashboards.

Comment: thanks for the input:
The "Started Hi", "Started Lo" apporach actually is a solution, which I had implemented allready yesterday. My customer didn't like it and also wants the possibility to have a third dimension in the future..
Option two with the summary list won't work in my case as I'd also have to copy list item permissons, which I have in the base list.

I'm actually looking into the jquer pivot plugin, which at least supports multiple y dimensions. http://metalogic.dk/jquery.pivot/demo.htm

And ther is no difference started and in progress. I just wasn't thinking when writing up the ex

Comment: You got me intrigued so I've been trying to find a way to pull it off with a Data View Web Part, but I keep coming up short. It may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Performance Point Services reports can be only created with OLAP Data and not tabular data, but using Power Pivot as staging and also to build cubes..so in short, read the data  into PowerPivot, build the cube and design the Reports in Performance Point.

Set the cache to 0 minutes and data refresh job for 1-5 min, I know it would be a overkill but can be done this way :)